# Recursion in sequences

Tags: java, loops, integer

I'm trying to make my Hailstone sequence output the smallest integer that cannot be computed due to the restrictions on int, but for some reason it still is not working. Any ideas as to why it's not would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=2; 
        int count = x;
        //Collatz Conjecture computation
        while (true)
        {   x=2; 
            x =count;
            while (x != 1)
            {   
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    x = x / 2;
                if (x % 2 == 1)
                    x = x * 3 + 1;
                if (x < 0)
                {   System.out.print("The integer " + count + " cannot have its Hailstone sequence computed using int variables. ");
                    return;
                }
            }
            count ++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: When I run the program it does not output anything. Even though I have it set to output that integer value once found.

Comment: Get out a pen and paper and step through the program like the computer would. Write down each variable and the values assigned to them. Does x ever less than 0?

Comment: When there is an overflow error it starts at the negative integer range of the int restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `Hailstone sequence` will reach an [unending sequence](http://plus.maths.org/content/mathematical-mysteries-hailstone-sequences) of `4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, ...`, because, you are having multiple `if's` instead of `if-else`.

You should change your set of `if's` to: -

```
if (x % 2 == 0)
    x = x / 2;
else
    x = x * 3 + 1;
if (x < 0) {   
    System.out.print("The integer " + count + " cannot have its Hailstone sequence computed using int variables. ");
    return;
}
```

---

**So, what was the Issue?**

If you were using just `if's`, then at one point of time, your `x` will become `1` due to first `if` condition.

So, with `x = 1`, the 2nd `if` would be executed, and `x` would now become - `1 * 3 + 1` = `4`. Then the while loop continues. Again, `x` becomes `2` (**1st `if`**), then again `while` loop continues (**As `2nd if` is not satisfied now. `2 % 2 != 1`**), and then `x` becomes `1` (**1st `if`**), then `4` (**2nd `if`**), and so on. This problem arise, because both your `if` blocks was getting executed everytime.

---

Just to complete the answer, I think you don't even need that last condition - `x < 0`. Your while loop will automatically break when `x becomes 1`. And this must be the only condition of ending the sequence. Because, once you start with value `1`, you would end up in that deadly sequence. So, just remove `if (x < 0)` part. **Not Needed.**

So, you should just use: -

```
if (x % 2 == 0)
    x = x / 2;
else
    x = x * 3 + 1;
```

in your `inner` while.

Comment: @A.R.S. yeah, but if x becomes 1 after dividing, the next step immediately pushes it up to 4 again if you use `if` instead of `else if`....

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you! I see the fault of my stupidity and should have caught that earlier. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: +1 But I would still stay away from `x < 0`, see the last part of my answer.

Comment: @user1860709. Note that OverFlow never occurs in case of multiplication operation. So, your `x < 0` will never be true. Probably you also need to modify it.

Comment: I would replace `if (x%2 == 1)` with `else` rather than `else if` -- after all, if the number wasn't even, it must be odd.

Comment: @MelNicholson.. Holy freak. You noticed that. Let me edit before any one else sees that.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at what you're actually doing. Your print statement is located within the if-statement with condition `x < 0`, but `x` will *never* be less than `0`. The two operations you are performing on `x` are: `x = x / 2` and `x = x * 3 + 1`. Neither of these can turn a positive into a negative.

---

***EDIT:*** Now I understand that `x < 0` was meant to test for an int overflow. Bear in mind that there is no guarantee that this will occur, the sequence could just get caught in a cycle (and probably will for most initial `x`, since you will have such a cycle once the sequence reaches `1`), although if this happens your `while`-loop would break and you would get no output. An alternative (as I indicated in my comment) would be to have `x` be of type `long` (i.e. `long x = ...`) and let the if-condition be `x > Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

---

Also, take a look at this:

```
int n = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(3 * n + 1);
```

```
2147483646
```

There is clearly an overflow but the result of `3*n + 1` is still positive.

---

And *finally*, there seems to be a problem with your first two `if`-statements (the second should be an `else if`), as indicated in the other answer. I'm just mentioning it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I have it set to 0 because it will cause an overflow error which will throw it in the the negative integer range. What other solution is viable then?

Comment: @user1860709 Oh I see, how about using `long` and then checking if `x > Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I just tried that and I still get no output at all. I changed x to a long and then set `if (x > Integer.MAX_VALUE)` yet still no output at all

Comment: I set my initial `x` as `long x = 2` and set the if statement to MAX_VALUE but still nothing.